# UITextView Fixed Size and Stop Auto Resizing

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitextview

I'm trying to add an editable text block to a `UIScrollView` (so the text blocks scroll when the keyboard shows up) which buttons can change.  The problem is creating the `UITextView` programmatically and adding it to the `UIScrollView`'s subview prevents buttons from being able to access the `UITextView.text`.  So I added the `UITextView` in the `ScrollView` in the `storyboard`, but then the `UITextView` is autoresized to 1 character since it starts with no text.  I've tried using a `CGRectMake`, but the `UITextView` won't keep the `width` fixed.  The user won't be able to see their texting with just 1 character visible at a time.

Suggestions on how to have a fixed width, editable `textView`, added to a `scrollView` so the keyboard can show, which doesn't automatically resize?

Here is my code:

```
@interface InventoryViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textTitle;

@end

@implementation InventoryViewController 

@synthesize textTitle;

-(void) createViewwithTitle {
    UIView *whiteView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 400.0f)];
    whiteView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    CGSize containerSize = CGSizeMake(320.0f, 400.0f);
    self.containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect) {.origin = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f), .size=containerSize}];
    [self.scrollView setDelegate:self];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.containerView];

    postion = CGRectMake(122.0f, 34.0f, 178.0f, 30.0f);
    [textTitle setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [textTitle setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    [textTitle setFrame:postion];
    [textTitle setText:@""];
    [whiteView addSubview:textTitle];
}

- (IBAction)buttonQuantityAdd:(id)sender {

    [self updateRecordwithTitle:textTitle.text];
}

@end
```

This is what I am trying to achieve:

[image: What I want]

This is what I get using the UITextView and the code above...

[image: What I have]

Comment: **The problem is creating the UITextView programmatically and adding it to the UIScrollView's subview prevents buttons from being able to access the UITextView.text...**

that's not necessarily true. you can define a variable inside your view controller and you'll have access to the text inside your controller as well! in fact, there is no difference between adding `UITextView` in storyboard or code in that aspect, if you need to work with it you need to define an accessible variable (either an IBOutlet from storyboard or a property or instance variable).

Comment: if you use auto layout, set the constraints for fixed width/height

Comment: Using Autolayout is very tricky, if you decided to do so (which is very wise) and still couldn't get the result you are looking for, you need to play with their priorities (content hugging and all)

Comment: The text view is a scroll view, why do you need it in a scroll view?

Comment: I showed the results of the code above.  I want the textview in the scroll view so when the keyboard shows, the user can still scroll though the current set of text input blocks even though they only have half the screen.